# Проверка массива на возврастание

Tags: java, массивы

Понятно как узнать, что массив строго возврастающий или убывающий:

```
public void dec(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of values: ");
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int [] mas= new int[n];

//        заполнение массива
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            mas[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

//        вывод массива
        for (int i = 0; i <mas.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(mas[i]+" ");
    }
//        проверка массива на возврастание
        boolean flag = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if (mas[i]<mas[i-1]) {
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
        if (mas[i]>mas[i-1]) {
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    if (flag==true) {
        System.out.println("Возврастающий");
    }
    if (flag==false) {
        System.out.println("убывающий");
    }
```

}

Но как добавить еще условие о том, что массив является ***ни убывающим, ни возврастающим*** ? При массиве 1 3 2, у меня выдается, что массив убывающий.

Comment: я бы сравнил полученный массив, с таким же, но отсортированным в порядке возрастания(проверка на возрастающий) или на осторитрованный в порядке убывания(убывающий). А если ни первая ни вторая проверка не прошли - то массив ни возрастающий, не убывающий

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить ещё один флаг на "не то, не то". В коде установки первого флага необходимо будет проверять, какой флаг у вас уже стоит до этого и, если новый и старый различны - устанавливать значение второго на `true`, значение которого позже проверите при выводе. Кодом (внутри цикла):

```
boolean tFlag = false; //Для хранения нового значения флага
if (mas[i]<mas[i-1]) {
  tFlag=false;
  break;
}
if (mas[i]>mas[i-1]) {
  tFlag=true;
}
if(i > 1 && (flag != tFlag)) { //Если убывало и возрастает (или наоборот)
  flag2 = true; //"Не то, не то"
  break;
} else {
  flag = tFlag; //Всё хорошо или первая итерация
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете к примеру не использовать флаг а задействовать счётчик и для каждой итерации в зависимости от фазы или инкриментить или дикриментить.
 По окончании цикла проверте на соответствие длинны массива и отсюда формируйте вывод.
Как вы понимаете не равный покажет смешанность. Иначе если болле 0 возрастающий в остатке убывающей.